# Paypal redirects to https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=

Tags: paypal

We have a Paypal form with action url https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. But when I try, it redirects to https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=3NU91602JE708862H&useraction=commit&rm=0&mfid=1551850187818_df17071ef4162#/checkout/guest and shows a card page as in the screen-shot.

[image]

But when my client tries this from some other location, it redirects to PayPal login page even without card button.

[image]

Does anybody have an idea on this? Any help will be appreciated.